# Connect an external display, close lid and avoid sleep on MacBook

Tags: macos, display, software-rec, sleep, standby

So I want to connect an external display, close my laptop lid and let the other display stay on (e.g. to watch a movie or something).

I found the app `NoSleep` which works if I don't connect an external display and just stream some music to a music setup and close my lid, the music will continue to play, however it sadly doesn't work with an external display.

Is there some piece of software (or some terminal command, or some Cocoa function, etc) that can do this?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple [provides a solution for this](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201834), actually.

These are the instructions, assuming you are using a Wired USB keyboard and mouse:

1. Make sure your Mac notebook is plugged in to an outlet using the AC
   power adapter.
2. Connect a USB keyboard and mouse to your Mac.
3. With your Mac turned on and the display open, connect the Mac to the
   appropriate port on the external display or projector and turn the
   display or projector on. Use an appropriate Apple video adapter if
   necessary.
4. After your Mac notebook's Desktop appears on the external display,
   close the computer's lid.

   When you close the lid:

   - In OS X Lion v10.7 and later, the external display changes to a blue
     screen, then shows your Desktop.
   - In OS X v10.6.8 and earlier, you can
     wake your Mac by clicking the mouse button or pressing a key on the
     external keyboard.

Effectively, you simply require AC power, and a mouse and keyboard connected, in order to make the display stay active.

Comment: And the last point:
5. Once the lid is closed, wake the computer up by either clicking your mouse button or by pressing a key on your external keyboard.

Comment: What about bluetooth keyboard / mouse?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you need is a connected and currently working external keyboard and mouse. Then closing the lid does the right thing, though you might have to move your mouse to get it out of sleep if your OS version is prior to 10.7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this app, but it is a popular one in the community

**Caffeine**

*Caffeine is a tiny program that puts an icon in the right side of your menu bar. Click it to prevent your Mac from automatically going to sleep, dimming the screen or starting screen savers. Click it again to go back. Right-click (or ⌘-click) the icon to show the menu.*

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12

Comment: Sadly this won't work as it only works when the lid is open

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Amphetamine available at [Amphetamine @ app store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704), which is used to set the options to use with the display closed and on battery power. I'm doing this as I write this up.

The OS X version I'm currently running is Big Sur (11.0.1)